# NULL queries getting stuck and using up connections

Tags: performance, phpmyadmin, process, query-performance

Running `show processlist` in phpmyadmin for me often shows queries with an Info of NULL and a Time of apparently a few seconds, but which have in fact been stuck there for a long time (each time I run `show processlist` the same Id may have a different Time). I have no idea what these queries are or why they get stuck, but they can often cause all my available connections to be used up and stuck on waiting in apache status, causing sites not to load. Is there a setting I can change to terminate queries that are stuck for a long time? Is the php.ini setting max_execution_time responsible for this (I had it set to 3000 from the default 90).

I have attached a screenshot of running `show processlist`.

[image]

Comment: two questions: 1) What do you think a proces with the command `sleep` does?     and 2) Can you give more info on ` causing sites not to load` do you get an error your DB is not available? or ….. (anything else?)

Comment: 1) I have no idea what these processes are doing or how/why they're starting 2) the sites just time out